# <ul> function is not working properly

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, html-lists, stylesheet

I want to implement a dropdown menu in a wordpress theme. `<ul>` function is not working properly because there are in both files **CSS** theme and menu. Maybe there is a conflict between these two **CSS** files for `<ul>` function. How can i make to work separate from each other the `<ul>` function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<ul id="firstul">
<li></li>
</ul>

<ul id="secondul">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice, but i'm not sure how can i set this because i have much lines with `<ul>` in theme and menu files.

Comment: You might need an experienced dev? You need to find which template is using that ul - start there. Depending on which theme you have it may make use of a custom Walker class which will dictate the navigation's markup.

Comment: I use just one theme. So i have 2 style css files. One file for wordpress theme and one file for dropdown megamenu. **Steve Bals** gave me an idea but im not sure how can i implement it. I do not think it's hard, but do not know how to do that.